# The results were interesting—until they weren't

Tags: word-usage

Do "they" in the phrase "The results were interesting—until **they** weren't" refer back to "the results"?

> Sam Harris tweeted today:

> I've deleted those polls due to the fact that so many people were not perceiving them as polls. **The results were interesting—until they weren't.** Sorry for the confusion.

> Source:  [Twitter](https://twitter.com/SamHarrisOrg/status/1384649910528581632)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it appears that the writer is saying

> The results were interesting. Until the results were no longer interesting.

It is unclear - at least to me - what he means by this. Maybe the results are no longer interesting because they are old? Or maybe because they were being misinterpreted. Hard to know. But "they" definitely was referring back to the results.

Comment: He is simply saying that the results were interesting at some point and  then were no longer interesting. It’s hard to see how that could be unclear. He does not raise a question about why. Not in this tweet.